# NODEJS sending raw request issue

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

I have an app and I would like to use it as a proxy. Code looks like this
I am using request npm.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.url); //lower case
 console.log(req.url.substr(0, 5));
 var alteredRequest;
 if (req.url.substr(0,5) == '/pro/') {

   var requestedURL = req.url.substr(5);
   console.log(requestedURL);
   if( (requestedURL.substr(0, 7) != 'http://') || (requestedURL.substr(0, 8) != 'https://') ){
     alteredRequest = "http://" + requestedURL;
   }
   request(alteredRequest, function(error, response, body){

     console.log('error: ', error); // Print the error if one occurred
     console.log('statusCode: ', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received


     res.send(response);

   })
 }
})
```

When I call `res.send(response)` at the end I get the response as a body, and all the headers exc are taken to the html body logged to the screen. Rather than that, I would like to send it as a real response with all the headers and cookies. How do I achieve it? thank you for helping.

To do more demonstration, the response (from google.com) starts like this, but it's on the screen! not the real headers and statusCode:

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":"<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.org/WebPage\" lang=\"tr\"><head><meta content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"><meta content=\"/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png\" itemprop=\"image\"><title>Google</title><script nonce=\"fzz0lJtfXqp5SuC6mvodsw==\">(function(){window.google=
```

Answer (score 0):

1. it's a really bad way to do redirects. You should be using
   res.redirect and req.protocol to do that
2. `if (req.url.substr(0,5) == '/pro/')` is perhaps the most hideous way of catching a route I've ever seen. This is what `app.get('/', ...)` is designed for.

But to answer your question, here's a working example

```js
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const app = express();

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  const newUrl = 'http://www.google.com'; //replace with your url altering code
  return request(newUrl)
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']) 
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(res);
});
app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: I have done it, I took every header in a for loop and set them for response. And no it is not. App.get is a better way to handle things, but when you have url which is app.get('/proxy/https:/sad') the program can't get the the param after proxy, it returns undefined. So no, it is not. Please don't judge everything

Comment: not judging, just trying to point you to a better way of doing things. But I'm not going to do it for you so you can take my advice or not. I hope .pipe will solve your immediate problem.

Comment: @turmuka, I've edited the response so now you have a full, working example that you should be able to use to achieve what you are trying to achieve.